# How do I get authenticated in bittrex? What is wrong with this code?

Tags: authentication

I used to use bittrex version 1 api. It worked well. Then, they change API and they change a lot.

So I am trying to get balances of my account in bittrex

```
Protected Overrides Async Function getJsonPrivateAsync(method As String, otherParameters() As Tuple(Of String, String)) As Task(Of String)
'Return ""


Dim url = "https://api.bittrex.com/v3/" + method 'https://api.bittrex.com/v3/balances
Dim apiTimeStamp = jsonHelper.currentTimeStamp() '1655809917684
Dim hasher = New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(""))
Dim contentHash = ExchangesClass.getString(hasher.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(""))) 'b936cee86c9f87aa5d3c6f2e84cb5a4239a5fe50480a6ec66b70ab5b1f4ac6730c6c515421b327ec1d69402e53dfb49ad7381eb067b338fd7b0cb22247225d47
Dim presig = apiTimeStamp.ToString + url + "GET" + contentHash '1655809917684https://api.bittrex.com/v3/balancesGETb936cee86c9f87aa5d3c6f2e84cb5a4239a5fe50480a6ec66b70ab5b1f4ac6730c6c515421b327ec1d69402e53dfb49ad7381eb067b338fd7b0cb22247225d47


Dim hasher1 = New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_secret1))
Dim sighash = ExchangesClass.getString(hasher.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(presig))) 'convert bytes to string

Dim response = Await CookieAwareWebClient.downloadString1Async(url, "", {Tuple.Create("Api-Key", _apiKey1), Tuple.Create("Api-Timestamp", apiTimeStamp.ToString), Tuple.Create("Api-Content-Hash", contentHash), Tuple.Create("Api-Signature", sighash)})

If response = "" Then
    Dim b = 1
End If
'Dim jo = JObject.Parse(response)

Return response
End Function
```

I followed instruction in https://bittrex.github.io/api/v3#topic-Authentication

Everything should be working.

Some of the function that I make is also pretty simple.

The `ExchangeClass.getString` simply convert bytes to hex

`downloadString1Async` simply put tuples of additional headers.

I simply get message that I am not authorized and I have no idea where I went wrong.

Perhaps the only thing I have a hard time understanding is

this code in

https://bittrex.github.io/api/v3#topic-Authentication

```
var contentHash = CryptoJS.SHA512(JSON.stringify(requestBody)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
```

This one has problem because I have no idea what requestBody is for. However, for read only API like checking balances that's just empty right?

All feedback I am getting is access denied or prohibited. I have on idea where I went wrong